# Move form on right click while resizing

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to move the form instead of resizing it while I'm resizing if the right button is down.

**Resize event:**

```
if (rightMouseDown)
{
    this.SetDesktopLocation(MousePosition.X - this.Width, MousePosition.Y - this.Height);
    this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(this.Width, this.Height);
    this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(this.Width, this.Height);
}
```

**Global mouse event:**

```
bool rightMouseDown;
private void HoldMouse(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && e.Clicks != 1)
        {
            rightMouseDown = true;
        }
        else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            rightMouseDown = false;
            this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
        }
}
```

At the moment when I click the right button it freezes because the MaximumSize is constant, therefore I can't resize the form.
e.cancel would be awesome if it would work but I can't use that.

I'm able to capture the mouse events with a global one, the form events doesn't work weirdly.

**I Got it working but only when the window's width is minimum and it goes to it's original width after the right mouse button goes up.**

**This is due to setting it to the default size. How can I keep the window in the changed size without setting it to MaximumSize 0,0?**

Comment: I use the MetroFramework for WinForms. Maybe that's why I can't capture the right mouse button event. But I should find another way, I'm almost there.

Comment: "move the form instead of resizing it while I'm resizing" really?

Comment: @MikeNakis Yes really, only when you hold the right mouse button down it does that, this way a user doesn't have to go to the upper bar and click it with the left button, then go back to the bottom right corner. I am not asking for UX feedback.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I would suggest that you ***do not*** move the form while the right button is down, because this is highly non-standard and therefore likely to be perceived as highly peculiar by anyone trying to use your app.  To be more specific, nobody is ever going to try either moving or resizing your form with the right mouse button, so:

1. if that's the only way you offer for moving your form, then nobody will ever be able to move your form.
2. if you also offer other ways of moving your form, then why bother with offering this way too?

Secondly, I would like to propose that this is most probably an [**X-Y problem**](http://xyproblem.info) meaning that you probably have some other issue, which you have told us nothing about, you *think* that you might address it by moving-by-right-click, then you discover that moving-by-right-click does not work for you, and you come here asking how to get moving-by-right-click to work.  Why don't you begin by describing the real issue?

Thirdly, if you really want to proceed with moving your form by right-click, that's not how to do it.

First, you need to detect when the right mouse button is pressed. There are events for this.  They work.  If they don't work for you, that's not a reason to be doing other weird things instead.  The statement "I'm not able to capture the mouse click with the Mouse events" is utterly bizarre, because a) it is a wrong use of the term "capture"; mouse capture is a very specific thing, (more about it later,) so please refrain from using it in other contexts, and b) if you cannot accomplish something, then that should be the subject of a stackoverflow question ***on its own***.  You cannot be trying utterly bizarre things because your attempts to do the right things failed.

So, once you have gotten detection of the right mouse click to work, then you need to set up mouse capture.  (Look it up, search for "SetCapture".)  That's what guarantees that you can keep receiving mouse move events, and finally a mouse-up event, even though the mouse has moved outside of your form while you were dragging it.

Comment: I do offer people to move it with the upper bar, but there are buttons there what makes it harder, plus my program is made to be resized and moved A LOT. If I just show a tooltip how it works it probably will work much better. And I just got the mouse event working now, but it's still not moving.

Comment: I see.  Well, then perhaps you have legitimate reasons for wanting to give users more ways of moving the window; but this still does not necessarily mean that it should be done with the right mouse button.  I have seen applications that do that, and I do not know whether they offer moving by the right mouse button because I have never even tried such a bizarre thing, but what they usually do is that they allow moving by left-dragging anywhere within their entire (small, usually) window.

Comment: This in turn means that they do have a somewhat involved handling of the mouse: you can obviously not use the mouse to drag within the window, because that moves the window.  But it does not mean that you cannot use the mouse at all: clicks can still work, only on mouse up instead of mouse down, because at the time of mouse up you know whether it was a click or a drag.

Comment: Yep I think I can better use the alt button, that you can use anywhere to just transport the window to your mouse. Thanks :) And thanks for the dislike whoever gave that to me :(

Comment: fixed that for you.